# How to edit spacing between Flutter's TextFormField input and errorText

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to decrease the spacing between the actual input and the error text in a TextFormField widget? As it stands right now having error texts displayed on the form almost doubles the size of the form and I would like to keep the form area the same size with or without error text. From the pictures below you can see how much change it makes and that there is quite a lot of space between the input and the error message that could use reducing.

[Form before errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NeT6.png)
[Form after errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMnQf.png)

Here is an example of one of the formfields

```
Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: myFocusNodeName,
                  controller: signupNameController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "WorkSansSemiBold",
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    icon: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.user,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    errorText: signupLastNameErrorText,
                    hintText: "Last Name",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "WorkSansSemiBold", fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                  validator: (value) =>
                      value.isEmpty ? 'Last Name can\'t be empty' : null,
                  onSaved: (value) => _lastname = value,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Use `errorStyle` property to edit error font size.

Comment: @anmol.majhail Right, I had already tried doing that, but I don't want the font to be smaller as that would make it harder to read, just closer to the actual input. I was hoping there would be a way to edit that padding or margin of the errorText itself

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add decoration in TextFormField Widget.

```
InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, right: 3, top: 14, bottom: 14),
      errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, height: 0.3),
)
```

Comment: the error doesn't show properly if the error exceeds 1 line

Answer (score 4):

The vertical padding of `errorText` is set in `input_decorator.dart`:

```dart
final double helperErrorHeight =
        !helperErrorExists ? 0 : helperError.size.height + subtextGap;
```

The `subtextGap` is a static constant and equal to `8.0`. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to override that value.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no way to do it unless you open the source code of InputDecoration (on your sdk folder flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart)

look for _buildError
wrap the Text with Container like

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
    child: Text(
        widget.errorText,
        style: widget.errorStyle,
        textAlign: widget.textAlign,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: widget.errorMaxLines,
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solutions,
You can using:

**maxLength**
For each TextFeild, 
=> You will have space you want when show error,
Affter that you can transparent color counter,
It Worked,

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create a subclass of `FormField`, handle validation and showing the error manually and delegate all other functionality down to `TextFormField`.

```
class TextFormField2 extends FormField<String> {
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final int? minLines;
  final int? maxLines;
  final double subtextGap; // <-- Gap between input and error text

  final TapRegionCallback? onTapOutside;
  final void Function(String value)? onChanged;

  TextFormField2(
      {this.controller,
      super.initialValue,
      this.focusNode,
      this.onTapOutside,
      this.onChanged,
      this.style,
      this.minLines,
      this.maxLines,
      this.subtextGap = 2,
      super.validator,
      super.autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      InputDecoration? decoration})
      : super(
          builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: controller,
                  initialValue: state.value,
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  onTapOutside: onTapOutside,
                  style: style,
                  minLines: minLines,
                  maxLines: maxLines,
                  decoration: decoration?.copyWith(
                    prefix: Container(
                      width:
                          (decoration.contentPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.left ?? 0,
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 0,
                      top: (decoration.contentPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.top ?? 0,
                      right:
                          (decoration.contentPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.right ??
                              0,
                      bottom:
                          (decoration.contentPadding as EdgeInsets?)?.bottom ??
                              0,
                    ),
                    // Used to create space for the error message so when the validation
                    // error is shown, there is no jumpy behavior
                    // counterText: ' ',
                    // counterStyle: Styles.error,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    state.didChange(value);
                    onChanged?.call(value);
                  },
                ),
                if (state.hasError) ...[
                  SizedBox(height: subtextGap),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        state.errorText!,
                        style: Styles.error,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]
              ],
            );
          },
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change text height, but I noticed that the animation is jumping.

I found another solution. Problem located in *material/input_decorator.dart* file. In **_RenderDecoration** class. It contains:

```
static const double subtextGap = 8.0;
```

I copied all files, remove InputDecorationTheme and changed value to **0.0.**

It also contains InputDecoration. I extended InputDecoration and remove override methods:

```
class CustomInputDecoration extends InputDecoration
```

And then i used it in the component:

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: CustomInputDecoration(...)
```

My flutter version: 2.2.1. I noticed that flutter team often rewrites components, so be careful! There may be changes in next releases.